# PHP MySQL PDO - Create EVENT to Excecute two Queries

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to create an event that will contain 2 (or more) update queries. Here is what I tried

```
$query1 = "CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS 'event name'
           ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
           DO
           UPDATE 'table1' SET 'myset'='1' WHERE 'something' ='1'
           UPDATE 'table2' SET 'active'='off' WHERE 'somethingelse'='1';";
```

I can do it by creating 2 events and place each update with one event but they will be to many events.

**Edit:** The problem is that this code will create an event that will contain *only* the first UPDATE inside, the second UPDATE is lost.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put a `;` after first UPDATE too. Like:

```
$query1 = "CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS 'event name'
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
DO
UPDATE 'table1' SET 'myset'='1' WHERE 'something' ='1';
UPDATE 'table2' SET 'active'='off' WHERE 'somethingelse'='1';
";
```

Comment: no its not working i also tried various things over the internet
this for example http://prntscr.com/c3lmpe
will create this http://prntscr.com/c3ln5m
it only takes the first line of code not the second